# Java - Simple output to a text file. What am I not seeing?

Tags: java

(I was hoping to get a text rendition of the files I am generating as input to the Knapsack Problem, in order to ckeck the results of a bottom-up version I am writing.)  However, this simple instantiation of `FileWriter` is not working.  Could someone take a minute and give me a hint?  Thanks!
P.S.  This is just my latest attempt to accomplish this simple task.  I hope it is not trivially incorrect, but what I cannot pin down is that the object meant to handle the output not being “resolved”.

```
import java.util.Random; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter; 

public class MainFrag {

       static int N = 20, Capacity;   
       static ArrayList<Integer> w = new ArrayList<>(N);
       static ArrayList<Integer> v = new ArrayList<>(N);

       static Random rand = new Random(42);

       public static void main(String[] args) { 
              while (w.size()<=N) { w.add( rand.nextInt(N*2)+1); }
              while (v.size()<=N) { v.add( rand.nextInt(N*2)+1); }
              Capacity = (int) (N * 0.50 * N*2);

//  **The FileWriter instance, outFile, “cannot be resolved”**

             PrintWriter outFile = null;
             try {     
                          outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt")); 
                      for (int i : w) { outFile.printf(" %3d", i); }
                      for (int i : v) { outFile.printf(" %3d", i); }

              } catch (Exception e) { 
                       System.err.print(e);
              } finally {     
                       outFile.close();
              }

        }
}
```

Comment: You're using  `java.io.PrintWriter`, but it doesn't appear that you've imported it.

Comment: Oh darn.  Thanks for the response, but I had inadvertently deleted that line line trying to make the question more readable.  I double checked that the syntax error is legit.  I will edit the question if I can.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get any errors? If so, which? Voting to close as this does not contain an explanation of the actual issue at hand (needs debugging details).

Comment: Note that you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase, and class names in PascalCase.

Comment: I put the error in the code where it occurs.  I fomated it bold, but that did not take, or it was edited out.

Comment: It is the syntax error:  “outFile cannot be resolved”.   I should have stressed that in the text.

Comment: @MC Emperor - I realize that I should not have named the size N.  It is an old habit.

Comment: And Capacity.   But seriously, I would think this should be a trivial task.  Is it nothing obvious?

Comment: Your example works correctly on my machine. Anyway you should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement when dealing with resources that should be closed.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that it should run.  I have been running it on my tablet in an app called J-Studio.  There must be a bug in his compiler?  Who knows!   Thanks Again.

Comment: P.S. I will look into the try-with-resources stuff.